# setState when this got changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For some reason I used jquery in my react's componentDidMount, but can't use this.setState, because this has been changed by jquery method, I set this to somewhere else, I can accept thisComponent.props.something but why setState failed?

```
componentDidMount() {
    const thisComponent = this //jquery changed `this`, thus set `this` set to somewhere else

    $('#container').on('scroll', function() {

        console.log(thisComponent.props.something) //work

        thisComponent.setState({ // not working
            myTestingState: true
        })
    })
}
```

There's no error, I tried print out {this.state.myTestingState.toString()} in my render method, it's just not been set.

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't work? Is there an error?

Comment: How exactly is it "not working"? What is happening instead? The value of `thisComponent` cannot and doesn't change between the two lines of code.

Comment: @FelixKling the state is not being set, no error. Note that I can't do this.props.something in the scroll method, this tie to jquery's, that's why I have to assign this to thisComponent, but it doesn't work for setState.

Comment: How do you know/verify that the state is not being set? *"I tried print out {this.state.myTestingState.toString()} in my render method"* does that mean you it always shows the same value?

Comment: @FelixKling I console.log(this.state) in my render method

Comment: And it does not show `myTestingState: true` ? What does it show instead? Is `render` actually executed after you set the state? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: FYI, where you say `jquery changed this` you are mistaken, it's just how `this` works in javascript in general

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
componentDidMount() {
    $('#container').on('scroll',() => {    
       this.setState({
          myTestingState: true
       })
    })
}
```

Comment: This can be further simplified, `thisComponent` is not needed anymore since by using an ES6 function, `this` remains unchanged.